# Question about the conditional statement ('m.if3') in the GEKKO

Tags: python, conditional-statements, gekko

I would like to add some conditional statements in the GEKKO code.

I added the below statement with 'm.if3'. However, it has returned syntax error that I didn't have without the conditional statement.

'R1_1 = m.if3(R1<0, 0, R1)'

```py
#%% GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)

#print(m.version)
#m.time = np.linspace(0, 3600, 100)
m.time = np.array([0,tstep])

cH = m.CV(value=cs0[0])
cM = m.CV(value=cs0[1])
cW = m.CV(value=cs0[2])
cF = m.CV(value=cs0[3])

R1_1 = m.Var()

r3 = m.Intermediate(r0*(1-cF/cFeMax)**(1/3))
r2 = m.Intermediate(r0*((2*cH + 3*cM)/cFeMax)**(1/3))
r1 = m.Intermediate(r0*(2*cH/cFeMax)**(1/3))
x = m.Intermediate(r1/r0)
y = m.Intermediate(r2/r0)
z = m.Intermediate(r3/r0)
A1 = m.Intermediate(1/x**2/(kd[0]*(1+1/Keq[0])))
A2 = m.Intermediate(1/y**2/(kd[1]*(1+1/Keq[1])))
A3 = m.Intermediate(1/z**2/(kd[2]*(1+1/Keq[2])))
B1 = m.Intermediate((y-x)/x/y*r0/Dif[1])
B2 = m.Intermediate((z-y)/y/z*r0/Dif[2])
B3 = m.Intermediate((1-z)/z*r0/Dif[3])
F = 0
W = m.Intermediate((A1+B1)*(A3*(A2+B2+B3+F)+(A2+B2)*(B3+F))+A2*(A3*(B2+B3+F))+B2*(B3+F))
ceq1 = m.Intermediate((cg0[0]+cg0[1])/(1+Keq[0]))
ceq2 = m.Intermediate((cg0[0]+cg0[1])/(1+Keq[1]))
ceq3 = m.Intermediate((cg0[0]+cg0[1])/(1+Keq[2]))

R1 = m.Intermediate(3/r0/W*((A3*(A2+B2+B3+F)+(A2+B2)*(B3+F))*(cg0[0]-ceq1) \
                     -(A3*(B2+B3+F)+B2*(B3+F))*(cg0[0]-ceq2) \
                     -A2*(B3+F)*(cg0[0]-ceq3)))
R2 = m.Intermediate(3/r0/W*(-(B2*(A3+B3+F)+A3*(B3+F))*(cg0[0]-ceq1) \
                     +((A1+B1+B2)*(A3+B3+F)+A3*(B3+F))*(cg0[0]-ceq2) \
                     -(A1+B1)*(B3+F)*(cg0[0]-ceq3)))
R3 = m.Intermediate(3/r0/W*(-A2*(B3+F)*(cg0[0]-ceq1) \
                    -(A1+B1)*(B3+F)*(cg0[0]-ceq2) \
                    +((A1+B1)*(A2+B2+B3+F)+A2*(B2+B1+F))*(cg0[0]-ceq3)))

R1_1 = m.if3(R1<0, 0, R1)

m.Equation(cH.dt() == nus[0].dot([R1_1, R2, R3]))
m.Equation(cM.dt() == nus[1].dot([R1_1, R2, R3]))
m.Equation(cW.dt() == nus[2].dot([R1_1, R2, R3]))
m.Equation(cF.dt() == nus[3].dot([R1_1, R2, R3]))

m.options.IMODE = 4
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.options.nodes = 2
```

Exception:  @error: Model Expression
 *** Error in syntax of function string: Mismatched parenthesis

Position: 4
 (0)))-((((1-int_v5))*(i35)-slk_1
    ?

Comment: I don't see `slk_1` anywhere in the code you posted. Are you sure this is the code with the error?

Comment: Good observation! Slack variables are automatically added when there is an inequality constraint to convert it back to an equality constraint (with the slack variable). The slk_1 is the additional variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need just one correction (remove the `<0`) to use the `if3` function in Gekko.

```py
R1_1 = m.if3(R1, 0, R1)
```

The `m.if3` function uses a condition that switches what is used (argument 2 or 3) based on whether the condition is less than zero or greater than or equal to zero. Here is the result of help (m.if3) with some additional explanation:

```
if3(condition, x1, x2) method of gekko.gekko.GEKKO instance

IF conditional with a binary switch variable.
The traditional method for IF statements is not continuously
differentiable and can cause a gradient-based optimizer to fail
to converge.

Usage: y = m.if3(condition,x1,x2)
Inputs:
   condition: GEKKO variable, parameter, or expression
   x1 and x2: GEKKO variable, parameter, or expression
Output: GEKKO variable y = x1 when condition<0
                       y = x2 when condition>=0
```

One other thing to consider is that the `if3` function uses binary variables and you'll need to use a Mixed Integer solver to find an integer solution. You can either remove the line that switches the solver to IPOPT (`if3` switches to the APOPT solver by default) or you can switch the option to APOPT manually.

```py
m.options.SOLVER = 1
```

Some of the constants were missing from your script. I added some dummy variables just to make it run.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

m = GEKKO()

help(m.if3)

tstep = 1.0
cs0=[1,1,1,1]
r0 = 1.0
cFeMax = 1.0
kd = [1,1,1]
Keq = [1,1,1]
Dif = [1,1,1,1]
cg0 = [1,1,1]
nus = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]])

m.time = np.array([0,tstep])

cH = m.CV(value=cs0[0])
cM = m.CV(value=cs0[1])
cW = m.CV(value=cs0[2])
cF = m.CV(value=cs0[3])

R1_1 = m.Var()

r3 = m.Intermediate(r0*(1-cF/cFeMax)**(1/3))
r2 = m.Intermediate(r0*((2*cH + 3*cM)/cFeMax)**(1/3))
r1 = m.Intermediate(r0*(2*cH/cFeMax)**(1/3))
x = m.Intermediate(r1/r0)
y = m.Intermediate(r2/r0)
z = m.Intermediate(r3/r0)
A1 = m.Intermediate(1/x**2/(kd[0]*(1+1/Keq[0])))
A2 = m.Intermediate(1/y**2/(kd[1]*(1+1/Keq[1])))
A3 = m.Intermediate(1/z**2/(kd[2]*(1+1/Keq[2])))
B1 = m.Intermediate((y-x)/x/y*r0/Dif[1])
B2 = m.Intermediate((z-y)/y/z*r0/Dif[2])
B3 = m.Intermediate((1-z)/z*r0/Dif[3])
F = 0
W = m.Intermediate((A1+B1)*(A3*(A2+B2+B3+F)+(A2+B2)*(B3+F))+A2*(A3*(B2+B3+F))+B2*(B3+F))
ceq1 = m.Intermediate((cg0[0]+cg0[1])/(1+Keq[0]))
ceq2 = m.Intermediate((cg0[0]+cg0[1])/(1+Keq[1]))
ceq3 = m.Intermediate((cg0[0]+cg0[1])/(1+Keq[2]))

R1 = m.Intermediate(3/r0/W*((A3*(A2+B2+B3+F)+(A2+B2)*(B3+F))*(cg0[0]-ceq1) \
                     -(A3*(B2+B3+F)+B2*(B3+F))*(cg0[0]-ceq2) \
                     -A2*(B3+F)*(cg0[0]-ceq3)))
R2 = m.Intermediate(3/r0/W*(-(B2*(A3+B3+F)+A3*(B3+F))*(cg0[0]-ceq1) \
                     +((A1+B1+B2)*(A3+B3+F)+A3*(B3+F))*(cg0[0]-ceq2) \
                     -(A1+B1)*(B3+F)*(cg0[0]-ceq3)))
R3 = m.Intermediate(3/r0/W*(-A2*(B3+F)*(cg0[0]-ceq1) \
                    -(A1+B1)*(B3+F)*(cg0[0]-ceq2) \
                    +((A1+B1)*(A2+B2+B3+F)+A2*(B2+B1+F))*(cg0[0]-ceq3)))

R1_1 = m.if3(R1, 0, R1)

m.Equation(cH.dt() == nus[0].dot([R1_1, R2, R3]))
m.Equation(cM.dt() == nus[1].dot([R1_1, R2, R3]))
m.Equation(cW.dt() == nus[2].dot([R1_1, R2, R3]))
m.Equation(cF.dt() == nus[3].dot([R1_1, R2, R3]))

m.options.IMODE = 4
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.options.nodes = 2

m.solve()
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer. I have a follow-up question. Can I add a conditional statement on the variables that appear in the 'm.Equation' directly in the m.Equation line? For example, for 'cH' in the equation. Or, do I need to add another dummy variable to set the condition?

Comment: Yes, you can add the function directly in the equation such as from this example you could remove the R1_1 variable with: ```m.Equation(cH.dt() == nus[0].dot([m.if3(R1, 0, R1), R2, R3]))```, ```m.Equation(cM.dt() == nus[1].dot([m.if3(R1, 0, R1), R2, R3]))```, ... It is better to define R1_1 once above and use it multiple times so that you minimize the additional variables that come with ```m.if3```.