# If else statement returning TypeError:object of type 'int' has no len() - Not sure why

Tags: python, typeerror, gekko

So, I am trying to solve an optimization problem. What I am trying to figure out is that when I run the code, my function call "to_fp_Cx" throws an error and I don't understand why.

The traceback keeps pointing to the functions I have defined. I tested these functions independently by calling it with different values and that worked as expected. So, I am not sure what is happening.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-3f717a4f07e1> in <module>
     37 # intermediate variables with explicit equations
     38 
---> 39 if(fload_c3_1 < 0.1):
     40     alt_fload_c3_1 = m.Intermediate(0)
     41 else:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_operators.py in __len__(self)
     23         return self.name
     24     def __len__(self):
---> 25         return len(self.value)
     26     def __getitem__(self,key):
     27         return self.value[key]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\gekko\gk_operators.py in __len__(self)
    142 
    143     def __len__(self):
--> 144         return len(self.value)
    145 
    146     def __getitem__(self,key):

TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

As the name suggests, I am a python noob and I am bamboozled. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
import numpy as np

# import gekko, pip install if needed
from gekko import GEKKO


# Compressor Performance curves
# Fraction capacity to Fractional power conversion

# Compressor C3
def to_fp_c3(fc):

    a = 5.16102738
    b = -16.25992208
    c = 18.52731113
    d = -8.859480201
    e = 2.096698885
    f = 0.334319989

    if (fc < 0.1):
        fp = 0.0
    else:
        fp = (a*fc**5)+(b*fc**4)+(c*fc**3)+(d*fc**2)+(e*fc**1)+(f*fc**0)

    return fp

...

### Optimization Model ####

# create new model
m = GEKKO(remote = False)

# Solver option - 1: APOPT, 2: BPOPT, 3: IPOPT 0:Benchmark all available
m.options.SOLVER = 3

# declare model parameters
maxcap_c3_1 = m.Param(value = 900)
maxcap_c3_2 = m.Param(value = 900)


load = m.Param(value = 1500)


## Model variables

# load distribution
fload_c3_1 = m.Var(value=0.50,lb=0.0,ub=1.0, integer = False)
fload_c3_2 = m.Var(value=0.50,lb=0.0,ub=1.0, integer = False)

# declare variables and initial guesses
#totalpowerdraw = m.Var()

# intermediate variables with explicit equations

if(fload_c3_1 < 0.1):
    alt_fload_c3_1 = m.Intermediate(0)
else:
    alt_fload_c3_1 = m.Intermediate(fload_c3_1)


if(fload_c3_2 < 0.1):
    alt_fload_c3_2 = m.Intermediate(0)
else:
    alt_fload_c3_2 = m.Intermediate(fload_c3_2)



assignedload_c3_1 = m.Intermediate(alt_fload_c3_1 * maxcap_c3_1)
assignedload_c3_2 = m.Intermediate(alt_fload_c3_2 * maxcap_c3_2)

powerdraw_c3_1 = m.Intermediate(to_fp_c3(alt_fload_c3_1) * maxcap_c3_1)
powerdraw_c3_2 = m.Intermediate(to_fp_c3(alt_fload_c3_2) * maxcap_c3_2)

totalpowerdraw = m.Intermediate(powerdraw_c3_1 + powerdraw_c3_2)


# implicit equations
m.Equation(load == assignedload_c3_1 + assignedload_c3_2 )


# minimize weight1
m.Obj(totalpowerdraw)

# solve optimization
m.solve()  # remote=False for local solve

print ('')
print ('--- Results of the Optimization Problem ---')
print (alt_fload_c3_1.value, powerdraw_c3_1.value)
print (alt_fload_c3_1.value, powerdraw_c3_2.value)
```

Comment: The code has ints, such as `fp = 0`. This is a lot of code for us to paw through. Can you make something short that still demonstrates the problem?

Comment: @tdelaney Shortened the code. Hope this is easier to navigate. Am I able to attach a jupyter notebook here ?

Comment: @usr2564301 Please see the edits. Thanks !

Comment: Can you pass 0 to Intermediate? Documentation says it receives an equation.

Comment: @SergioR I changed it to an equation that returns 0; still the same error.

Comment: @SergioR, good suggestion. The intermediate equation `m.Intermediate(0)` is valid. The problem is the `if` statement. I probably need to update the documentation to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `m.if3()` (or `m.if2()`) function from Gekko to make the conditional statement switch based on a Gekko variable. There is more information on conditional statements in [Question about the conditional statement ('m.if3') in the GEKKO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56676961/question-about-the-conditional-statement-m-if3-in-the-gekko)

```py
# use gekko if3 (or if2)
alt_fload_c3_1 = m.if3(fload_c3_1-0.1,0,fload_c3_1)
alt_fload_c3_2 = m.if3(fload_c3_2-0.1,0,fload_c3_2)
```

Here is a version of your program that gives a successful solution.

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

# Compressor Performance curves
# Fraction capacity to Fractional power conversion
# Compressor C3
def to_fp_c3(fc):
    a = 5.16102738
    b = -16.25992208
    c = 18.52731113
    d = -8.859480201
    e = 2.096698885
    f = 0.334319989
    fp = m.if3(fc-0.1,0,(a*fc**5)+(b*fc**4)+(c*fc**3)\
               +(d*fc**2)+(e*fc**1)+(f*fc**0))
    return fp

### Optimization Model ####
# create new model
m = GEKKO(remote = False)

# declare model parameters
maxcap_c3_1 = m.Param(value = 900)
maxcap_c3_2 = m.Param(value = 900)
load = m.Param(value = 1500)

## Model variables

# load distribution
fload_c3_1 = m.Var(value=0.50,lb=0.0,ub=1.0, integer = False)
fload_c3_2 = m.Var(value=0.50,lb=0.0,ub=1.0, integer = False)

# use gekko if3 (or if2)
alt_fload_c3_1 = m.if3(fload_c3_1-0.1,0,fload_c3_1)
alt_fload_c3_2 = m.if3(fload_c3_2-0.1,0,fload_c3_2)
assignedload_c3_1 = m.Intermediate(alt_fload_c3_1 * maxcap_c3_1)
assignedload_c3_2 = m.Intermediate(alt_fload_c3_2 * maxcap_c3_2)
powerdraw_c3_1 = m.Intermediate(to_fp_c3(alt_fload_c3_1) * maxcap_c3_1)
powerdraw_c3_2 = m.Intermediate(to_fp_c3(alt_fload_c3_2) * maxcap_c3_2)
totalpowerdraw = m.Intermediate(powerdraw_c3_1 + powerdraw_c3_2)

# implicit equations
m.Equation(load == assignedload_c3_1 + assignedload_c3_2 )

# minimize weight1
m.Obj(totalpowerdraw)

# solve optimization
m.solve()  # remote=False for local solve

print ('')
print ('--- Results of the Optimization Problem ---')
print (alt_fload_c3_1.value, powerdraw_c3_1.value)
print (alt_fload_c3_1.value, powerdraw_c3_2.value)
```

with the solution:

```py
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :  0.0313 sec
 Objective      :  1576.7914326000025
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------

--- Results of the Optimization Problem ---
[0.66761123885] [677.4476587]
[0.66761123885] [899.3437739]
```

Comment: Professor @John Hendengren, thank you ! This works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this

If(fload_c3_1.value < 0.1):

Comment: This is a good solution if the conditional statement is determined at initialization. For problems where the conditional statement depends on an optimization variable, I use the `m.if3()` or `m.if2()` functions.