# m.Equations resulting in TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: gekko

I'm having trouble passing my equations of motion to the solver on my control optimization problem.

Just a little explanation on what I'm attempting to do here, because I think there are two problem areas:

First, I'm defining a contact switch c that is used to turn on and off portions of the dynamic equations based on the value a, which is a FV between 0 and .45. I have a loop which sets the value of c[i] based on the value of the time parameter relative to a.

```py
c = [None]*N

for i in range(N):
    difference = m.Intermediate(.5-m.time[i])
    abs = m.if3(difference, -difference, difference)
    c[i] = m.Intermediate(m.if3(abs-(.5-a), 1, 0))
```

It should resemble a vector of length N:

```py
c= [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, ...., 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

It's not clear if this was implemented properly, but it's not throwing me errors at this point. (Note: I'm aware that this can be easily implemented as a mixed-integer variable, but I really want to use IPOPT, so I'm using the [m.if3() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56676961/question-about-the-conditional-statement-m-if3-in-the-gekko) to create the binary switch.)

Second, I'm getting an error when passing the equations of motion. This exists whether the c is included, so, at least for right now, I know that is not the issue.

```py
m.Equations(xdot.dt()/TF == c*u*(L1*m.sin(q1)-L2*m.sin(q1+q2))/(M*L1*L2*m.sin(2*q1+q2)))
m.Equations(ydot.dt()/TF == -c*u*(L1*m.cos(q1)+L2*m.cos(q1+q2))/(M*L1*L2*m.sin(2*q1+q2))-g/m)
m.Equation(x.dt()/TF == xdot)
m.Equation(y.dt()/TF == ydot)
m.Equation(y*init == y*final) #initial and final y position must be equal
```

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I've attempted to set up an intermediate loop to handle the RH of the equation to no avail:

```py
RH = [None]*N
RH = m.Intermediate([c[i]*u[i]*(L1*m.sin(q1[i])-2*m.sin(q1[i]+q2[i]))/(M*L1*L2*m.sin(2*q1[i]+q2[i])) for i in range(N)])
m.Equations(xdot.dt()/TF == RH)
```

Below is the full code. Note: there are probably other issues both in my code and problem definition, but I'm just looking to find a way to successfully pass these equations of motion. Much appreciated!

Full code:

```py
import math
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

#Defining a model
m = GEKKO(remote=True)
v = 1  #set walking speed (m/s)
L1 = .5 #set thigh length (m)
L2 = .5 #set shank length (m)
M = 75 #set mass (kg)

#################################
#Define secondary parameters
D = L1 + L2  #leg length parameter
pi = math.pi #define pi
g = 9.81 #define gravity

#Define initial and final conditions and limits
x0 = -v/2; xf = v/2
xdot0 = v; xdotf = v
ydot0 = 0; ydotf = 0
ymin = .5*D; ymax = 1.5*D
q1min = -pi/2; q1max = pi/2
q2min = -pi/2; q2max = 0
tfmin = D/(2*v); tfmax = 3*D/(2*v)

#Defining the time parameter (0, 1)
N = 100
t = np.linspace(0,1,N)
m.time = t

#Final time Fixed Variable
TF = m.FV(1,lb=tfmin,ub=tfmax); TF.STATUS = 1
end_loc = len(m.time)-1
amin = 0; amax = .45

#Defining initial and final condition vectors
init = np.zeros(len(m.time))
final = np.zeros(len(m.time))
init[1] = 1
final[-1] = 1

init = m.Param(value=init)
final = m.Param(value=final)

#Parameters
M = m.Param(value=M) #cart mass
L1 = m.Param(value=L1) #link 1 length
L2 = m.Param(value=L2) #link 1 length
g = m.Const(value=g) #gravity

#Control Input Manipulated Variable
u = m.MV(0); u.STATUS = 1

#Ground Contact Fixed Variable
a = m.FV(0,lb=amin,ub=amax)  #equates to the unscaled time when contact first occurs

#State Variables
x, y, xdot, ydot, q1, q2 = m.Array(m.Var, 6)

x.value = x0;
xdot.value = xdot0; ydot.value = ydot0
y.LOWER = ymin; y.UPPER = ymax
q1.LOWER = q1min; q1.UPPER = q1max
q2.LOWER = q2min; q2.UPPER = q2max

#Intermediates
c = [None]*N

for i in range(N):
    difference = m.Intermediate(.5-m.time[i])
    abs = m.if3(difference, -difference, difference)
    c[i] = m.Intermediate(m.if3(abs-(.5-a), 1, 0))

#Defining the State Space Model
m.Equations(xdot.dt()/TF == c*u*(L1*m.sin(q1)-L2*m.sin(q1+q2))/(M*L1*L2*m.sin(2*q1+q2))) ####This produces the error
m.Equations(ydot.dt()/TF == -c*u*(L1*m.cos(q1)+L2*m.cos(q1+q2))/(M*L1*L2*m.sin(2*q1+q2))-g/m)
m.Equation(x.dt()/TF == xdot)
m.Equation(y.dt()/TF == ydot)
m.Equation(y*init == y*final) #initial and final y position must be equal

#Defining final condition
m.fix_final(x,val=xf)
m.fix_final(xdot,val=xdotf)
m.fix_final(xdot,val=ydotf)

#Try to minimize final time and torque
m.Obj(TF)
m.Obj(0.001*u**2)

m.options.IMODE = 6 #MPC
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.solve()

m.time = np.multiply(TF, m.time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice application. Here are a few corrections and ideas:

1. Use a switch condition that uses a NumPy array. There is no need to define the individual points in the horizon with `c[i]`.

```py
#Intermediates
#c = [None]*N

#for i in range(N):
#    difference = m.Intermediate(.5-m.time[i])
#    abs = m.if3(difference, -difference, difference)
#    c[i] = m.Intermediate(m.if3(abs-(.5-a), 1, 0))
diff = 0.5 - m.time
adiff = m.Param(np.abs(diff))
swtch = m.Intermediate(adiff-(0.5-a))
c = m.if3(swtch,1,0)
```

You may be able to use the `m.integral()` function to set the value of `c` to 1 and keep it there when contact is made.

2. Use the `m.periodic(y)` function to set the initial value of `y` equal to the final value of `y`.

```py
#m.Equation(y*init == y*final) #initial and final y position must be equal
m.periodic(y)
```

3. Try using soft constraints instead of hard constraints if there is a problem with finding a feasible solution.

```py
#Defining final condition
#m.fix_final(x,val=xf)
#m.fix_final(xdot,val=xdotf)
#m.fix_final(ydot,val=ydotf)
m.Minimize(final*(x-xf)**2)
m.Minimize(final*(xdot-xdotf)**2)
m.Minimize(final*(ydot-ydotf)**2)
```

4. The `m.if3()` function requires the APOPT solver. Try `m.if2()` for the continuous version that uses MPCCs instead of binary variables to define the switch. The integral function may be alternative way to avoid a binary variable.

Here is the final code that attempts a solution, but the solver can't yet find a solution. I hope this helps you get a little further on your optimization problem. You may need to use a shooting (sequential method) to find an initial feasible solution.

```py
import math
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO

#Defining a model
m = GEKKO(remote=True)
v = 1  #set walking speed (m/s)
L1 = .5 #set thigh length (m)
L2 = .5 #set shank length (m)
M = 75 #set mass (kg)

#################################
#Define secondary parameters
D = L1 + L2  #leg length parameter
pi = math.pi #define pi
g = 9.81 #define gravity

#Define initial and final conditions and limits
x0 = -v/2; xf = v/2
xdot0 = v; xdotf = v
ydot0 = 0; ydotf = 0
ymin = .5*D; ymax = 1.5*D
q1min = -pi/2; q1max = pi/2
q2min = -pi/2; q2max = 0
tfmin = D/(2*v); tfmax = 3*D/(2*v)

#Defining the time parameter (0, 1)
N = 100
t = np.linspace(0,1,N)
m.time = t

#Final time Fixed Variable
TF = m.FV(1,lb=tfmin,ub=tfmax); TF.STATUS = 1
end_loc = len(m.time)-1
amin = 0; amax = .45

#Defining initial and final condition vectors
init = np.zeros(len(m.time))
final = np.zeros(len(m.time))
init[1] = 1
final[-1] = 1

init = m.Param(value=init)
final = m.Param(value=final)

#Parameters
M = m.Param(value=M) #cart mass
L1 = m.Param(value=L1) #link 1 length
L2 = m.Param(value=L2) #link 1 length
g = m.Const(value=g) #gravity

#Control Input Manipulated Variable
u = m.MV(0); u.STATUS = 1

#Ground Contact Fixed Variable
a = m.FV(0,lb=amin,ub=amax)  #equates to the unscaled time when contact first occurs

#State Variables
x, y, xdot, ydot, q1, q2 = m.Array(m.Var, 6)

x.value = x0;
xdot.value = xdot0; ydot.value = ydot0
y.LOWER = ymin; y.UPPER = ymax
q1.LOWER = q1min; q1.UPPER = q1max
q2.LOWER = q2min; q2.UPPER = q2max

#Intermediates
#c = [None]*N

#for i in range(N):
#    difference = m.Intermediate(.5-m.time[i])
#    abs = m.if3(difference, -difference, difference)
#    c[i] = m.Intermediate(m.if3(abs-(.5-a), 1, 0))
diff = 0.5 - m.time
adiff = m.Param(np.abs(diff))
swtch = m.Intermediate(adiff-(0.5-a))
c = m.if3(swtch,1,0)

#Defining the State Space Model
m.Equation(xdot.dt()/TF == c*u*(L1*m.sin(q1)
                                -L2*m.sin(q1+q2))
                           /(M*L1*L2*m.sin(2*q1+q2)))
m.Equation(ydot.dt()/TF == -c*u*(L1*m.cos(q1)
                                  +L2*m.cos(q1+q2))
                            /(M*L1*L2*m.sin(2*q1+q2))-g/M)
m.Equation(x.dt()/TF == xdot)
m.Equation(y.dt()/TF == ydot)
#m.Equation(y*init == y*final) #initial and final y position must be equal
m.periodic(y)

#Defining final condition
#m.fix_final(x,val=xf)
#m.fix_final(xdot,val=xdotf)
#m.fix_final(ydot,val=ydotf)
m.Minimize(final*(x-xf)**2)
m.Minimize(final*(xdot-xdotf)**2)
m.Minimize(final*(ydot-ydotf)**2)

#Try to minimize final time and torque
m.Minimize(TF)
m.Minimize(0.001*u**2)

m.options.IMODE = 6 #MPC
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()

m.time = np.multiply(TF, m.time)
```

Comment: As always, thank you John for your detailed responses! This at least solved my issues with code mechanics. A lot more to do with the constraints. I will look into shooting method if feasibility remains an issue. Thank you again.